# Windows asking me to sign in with a company email?

Tags: windows, kvm-virtualization, qemu

Windows is asking me to sign in with my company's email, problem is I don't have one and nor is the company related to me whatsoever. I am trying to run Windows LTSC on QEMU. What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens due to a UUID collision that affects Windows Autopilot which associates it to a company. You can fix this by supplying another UUID, or your system's UUID by inserting the flags

`-enable-kvm -uuid $(dmidecode -s system-uuid)`

Make sure the process is offline, by disabling your network adapter while in the OOBE process. Get an elevated prompt by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and executing the following in powershell:

`Disable-NetAdapter -Name "Adapter Name" -Confirm:$false`

You may get the adapter name by

`Get-NetAdapter`